# RCP Placeholder for StandaloneView

Tags: view, rcp, placeholder

I'm very new to RCP and I want to build a window with a *TreeViewer* as a menu on the left and views on the right.
When clicking on a *TreeItem* the current view should be replaced with the new page.
The Views shall not be moveable or closeable.

The menu works fine so far but I can't get the views to act like I want.

I tried using a Placeholder within my perspective:

```
layout.addStandaloneViewPlaceholder("gui.page:*", IPageLayout.TOP, 0.5f, editorArea, false);
```

The IDs of the views all start with gui.page...
When I add one of the pages as standaloneView to the perspective it looks just as I want it.
But when I add a *View* by calling

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(pageID);
```

in the listener of the *TreeViewer*, the Pages get tabbed and are move- and closeable.

A good example of what I want to have is the preferences dialog of eclipse. I searched in the eclipse source but I couldn't find the way they made it.

Any suggestions on how to make this?

Answer (score 1):

Views won't get replaced. So you have to hide the previous view by calling IWorkbenchPage.hideView()

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I got another tip from a workmate which I will use.
Instead of placing my different pages in views, they are now different composites inside a single view with a stacklayout.
Works just fine :)